# How to add syntax styling to Windows 10 Code Writer

Tags: windows-10

I'm quite liking Window's new Code Writer for quickly editing the various files that go along with a Salesforce + Marketing Cloud project (usually, SQL, JS, HTML, and AmpScript).

I would like to add a syntax for AmpScript. Is this possible with Window's Code Writer?

If not, are there other solutions similar to Code Writer that would allow a custom syntax to be added?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Advice that I got from Stack Overflow:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432614/how-to-add-syntax-styling-to-windows-10-code-writer)

> Windows UWP applications have limitations on how they can be extended
>   (a consequence of sandboxing).
>
> Since late 2016, UWP apps can have "App extensions" that work like
>   plugins, but still need approval from the Microsoft App Store and the
>   host application needs to permit it in the first place - and from what
>   I can see in the Code Writer app this isn't possible.
>
> A lightweight but powerful editor that might work is Notepad++ or a
>   heavier editor like VS Code which has a considerably larger ecosystem
>   of plugins, including one for AMPScript already.

[Credit to @Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai)